# How to add Mac OSX to cordova project

Tags: macos, cordova

I currently have a Cordova project with 2 platforms: Android and iOS
I'm trying to add "OSX" with this:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-osx

However the documentation is quite hard to follow and I can't seem to get it to work properly.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this? or more precise step by step instructions?

Answer (score 0):

The Cordova CLI does not support OSX project targets.

In your project working directory root, type in:

```
cordova platform list
```

... to see the available and installed platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I really appreciate it.
So if i've got it right I should create a new cordova project with the bin/create cmd then import the sources from my other project?

Answer (score 0):

just wondering if anyway gots this running ? actually I tried to load cordova from master. Later I tried to applied the patch which did NOT worked. So I did what the patch did by hand.

Anyway after the full cycle still "platform list" does not changed ?

So I assume there are more steps to be done, before OSX is added as a new platform?

Comment: No, sadly I wasn't able to use this solution. In the end, I ended up using node webkit which works great: https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit
You can't use cordova plugins however I didn't have any need for them.